# How to make if-statement print required the result?

Tags: c, if-statement

This code has one problem. The problem is in

**Problem in if-statement**

```
if(all_digits(to_find) && strlen(to_find) ==  13)
```

Whenever I enter 13 characters but not from the file then it gives me a message of else statement but printing `Found. Hello World!` also. Although `Found. Hello World!` is in if-statement. It should not be printed. How to make if-statement work correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int all_digits(char *s){
  for (; *s!=0; s++){
    if (!isdigit(*s)){
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

**Another part of code**

```
int main(){
  FILE * fr = fopen("file.csv", "r");

  char save[500], line[200],  to_find[50];
  int oneByOne = 0, numberOfFields=8;
  char *word = NULL;
  printf("Enter the ID card number: ");
  scanf("%s", to_find);

  if(all_digits(to_find) && strlen(to_find) ==  13){
    while(fgets(line, 200, fr)){
      word = strtok(line, "\n");
      strcpy(save, line);

      if (strstr(save, to_find)){
        char *wordone = strtok(save, ",");
        while (wordone != NULL){
          printf("Here are your details: %s\n", wordone);
          wordone = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
      }
    }
    fclose(fr);

    printf("Found. Hello World!\n");
  }  
  else {
    printf("enter correclty\n");
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: A general suggestion - combine your `all_digits` with `strlen` so it will traverse the string in one shot.

Comment: "*Whenever I enter 13 characters [...] it gives me a message of else statement  ...*" I cannot reproduces this.

Comment: It is working correctly. The computer is doing what you told it to.

Comment: `fclose(fr);` is called only when the if condition is met. It should be called outside it, at least when `fr != NULL` (that is actually a missing check).

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of _"it gives me a message of else statement"_. What message? Can you tell us the complete output you get and an example of the input string leading to that output?

Comment: `else {
    printf("enter correclty\n");
  }`

Comment: So your output is `Found. Hello World!\nenter correclty\n`? It sounds really strange..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run multiple tests without cascading if-thens you can use an error flag along with a one-time loop like so:

```
int err = 0; /* Be optimistic! (0 indicates success) */

do {
   if (!test1-passed) {
     err = 1;
     break;
   }

   if (!test2-passed) {
     err = 2;
     break;
   }

   ...

   if (!testN-passed) {
     err = N;
     break;
   }

   printf("Success! All tests passed");
} while (0);

if (err) {
  printf("Test %d failed", err);
}
```

Applied to you particular problem the code might look like this

```
... /* definitions here */

int err = 0; /* Be optimistic! (0 indicates success) */

do {
  ... /* input here */

  do {
    if (!all_digits(to_find)) {
      err = 1;
      break;
    }

    if (strlen(to_find) != 13) {
      err = 2;
      break;
    }

    {
      err = 3 /* be pessimistic! */

      while(fgets(line, 200, fr)){
        /* word = strtok(line, "\n"); */ /* word is not needed. */
        strcpy(save, line); /* Introducing save here is not necessary, 
                               all following operation can be applied to line. */

        if (strstr(save, to_find)){
          char *wordone = strtok(save, ",");
          while (wordone != NULL){
            printf("Here are your details: %s\n", wordone);
            wordone = strtok(NULL, ",");
            err = 0; /* Phew, we are lucky! */
          }
        }
      }

      if (err) {
        break;
      }
    }

    printf("Success! All tests passed");
  } while (0);

  if (err) {
    printf("Test %d failed", err);
  } 
} while (err);
```

Comment: There is only one if-statement inside while loop

Comment: Stare at my example, meditate and become enlightened... ;)

Comment: Okay, I will meditate. Thank you for enlightenment!

Comment: If you're going to use `goto`, have the courage to spell it `goto` :-P

Comment: @zwol: And *if* you tried to cascade such constructs using goto, then well ... no.